# Render a form function in multiple django templates

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have written a function where the function captures the details from a form and sends an email after form submission. How can I have this functionality rendered to multiple django templates where i can call the form and do so.
Below is the related function..

```
def emailView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = myform()
    else:
        form = myform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject='form Details'
            mobile = form.cleaned_data['mobile']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            dummy = '\nMobile: '+mobile+'\nEmail: '+email'
            try:
                send_mail(subject, dummy, 'dummy@gmail.com', ['dummy1@gmail.com', 'dummy2@gmail.com'])
                messages.success( request, " Thank you !! For contacting.')
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('email')
    return render(request, "my_app/email.html", {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use include tag to do so. Try out the below way.

consider the below as your url in urls.py

```
path('your_form/', views.emailView, name='myform'),
```

you can call your function any number of templates using the below tag.

```
#template1.html

<form method="post" action="{% url 'myform' %}">
{% include 'yourapp/email.html' %}
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

#template2.html

<form method="post" action="{% url 'myform' %}">
{% include 'yourapp/email.html' %}
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```